# Creating a label inside Gridview Cell from VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, label

I have some Code in VB that is looping through a gridview's rows and is checking the values of a certain collumn, I have written some code inside the if statement that creates a clickable label inside the cell for when the cell is "", I have already written a bit of code that could create my label but I'm not too sure how it would create it inside row.Cells(8)

I was wondering if could get some assistance with how I should be doing this?...

Here's my Code:

```
            For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
Dim row = GridView1.Rows(i)

Dim rowHeaderCell = row.Cells(8)
            If rowHeaderCell.Text = "&nbsp;" Then

Dim lbl As New Label
                lbl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(159, 23)
                lbl.Location =
                lbl.Text = "label text goes here"
                Me.Controls.Add(lbl)

            End If
        Next
```

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a clickable label change the type of the column to :   [DataGridViewLinkColumn]

here is the code to replace the Empty cell value by the value of LBL:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.Trim = "" Then
            Dim lbl As String
            lbl = "label text goes here "
            GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = lbl
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You're a life saver, How do I  change the type of the column to DataGridViewLinkColumn?